# How to visualize FlatIcon fonticon in xamarin ios native project?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

There is a problem about usage of Flaticon. I have imported .ttf file that I have downloaded and I have visual of FontIcon font style in my project. Here is a example code of implementation flaticon fonts.

```
   public static class FlatIcon
    {
        public static string FlaticonTwitterLogoSilhoutte = "\f100";
        public static string FlaticonGooglePlus = "\f101";
        public static string FlaticonFacebookLogo = "\f102";
        public static string FlaticonTick = "\f103";
    }
```

And here is the code that I am trying to visualize Icon.

```
FacebookIcon.Text = $"{FlatIcon.FlaticonFacebookLogo}";
```

I am not able to get output of what I expect and I am not able to understand why, can you help me with this issue?

Comment: Have you added the font to your info.plist under the `UIAppFonts` key? and where are you loading the font?

Comment: Yes here it is <key>UIAppFonts</key>
  <array>
    <string>Resources/Flaticon.ttf</string>
  </array> And I am able to see fontstlye visually in storyboard

Comment: And where are you loading the font? You have not included the code that is assigning the font to your UIKit control.

Comment: I have set Font to FlatIcon style and trying to load it in storyboard.

Comment: How do I assign it to UIKit control

Comment: Are you assigning the font filename or the actual font family name in your storyboard? Open the font in macOS's `Font Book` and ensure that the name shown in the title bar is the name that you are using in your Storyboard. In the Storyboard, add a User Defined Runtime Attribute to the control with Key `Path` set to your font name,

Comment: I have managed to add my fontstyle to the Font Book but there is no User Defined Runtime Attribute in xamarin. Should I add it with c# code?